# Why does $x_n^2$ converge to $x^2$ if $x_n$ converges to $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n$ be a convergent sequence converging to $x$

Then claim $x_n^2$ converges to $x^2$

I wish to use the definition to show this is the case.

Recall $x_n \to x$ iff $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N \Rightarrow |x_n - x| < \epsilon$

Then $|x_n^2 - x^2| = |x_n - x||x_n + x|$

But what is $|x_n + x|$?

$-\epsilon< x_n - x < \epsilon$
$\Rightarrow -\epsilon + 2x < x_n + x < \epsilon + 2x$

Then $|x_n^2 - x^2| = |x_n - x||x_n + x| < \epsilon(\epsilon+2x)$

But I wish to show that $|x_n^2 - x^2| < \epsilon$. How to deal with the $2x$ term?

Comment: Not really a hint, but it may help you to use a different letter to distinguish the two $\varepsilon$'s that are running around. (As Jane did with her $\varepsilon_0$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $x$ is fixed. Choose some $\epsilon>0.$ There exist some $\epsilon_0>0$, such that $\epsilon_0(\epsilon_0+2x)<\epsilon$

Since $x_n$ converges to $x$, there exist some $N>0$ such that for all $n>N$, we have $$|x_n-x|<\epsilon_0$$ and so, $$|x_n^2-x^2|<\epsilon_0(\epsilon_0+2x)<\epsilon.$$
This proves your statement.

Comment: Sorry but wouldn't that mean $\epsilon_0(\epsilon_0 + 2x)$ have to be arbitrarily small? We can make $\epsilon_0$ arbitrarily small but the $2x$ will always contribute something $> 0$, so $\forall \epsilon >0$ wouldn't be true. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Note that it is true for $x>0$. If $x<0$, then we are considering the absolute value of $(-\epsilon+2x)$

Comment: @MathNewb and it does not matter how big is $2x$, since we always can find such an $\epsilon_0$, which makes the product less than $\epsilon$

Comment: Oh you are right, there is a product here. If we drive $\epsilon_0$ small, then the whole thing goes small

Comment: @MathNewb exactly!